# jQuery custom Confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirmation

I want to have a very simple custom dialog. When I click remove, I want a simple panel opens up with the option to confirm or cancel. If confirmed, more things will run.

Since I want to use this confirmation in different files, this was my approach:

In index.js that runs on all pages I have:

```
var confirmation = -1
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').on({
        click: function() {
            confirmation = 1;
        }
    },'#confirmation_yes');

    $('html').on({
        click: function() {
            confirmation = 0;
        }
    },'#confirmation_no');
});

function confirmAction(callback)
{
    if( confirmation == 1 ) {
        $('#popup_panel').slideUp('slow', function(){
            $('#popup_fader').fadeOut('fast');
        });
        confirmation = -1;
            callback(true);
    }
    if( confirmation == 0 ) {
        $('#popup_panel').slideUp('slow', function(){
            $('#popup_fader').fadeOut('fast');
        });
        confirmation = -1;
        callback(true);     
    }
    setTimeout(confirmAction, 50)
}
```

So my idea was that then inside other JS files, we have

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    confirmAction(function(result){
        // do my stuff
    });
})
```

So when I do this, the system returns error and says "callback" is a not a function. What is wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: There is pure simple `confirm('Are you sure')` functionality

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use that. This is simplified example here, but I need to have my own dialog box opening.

Answer (score 0):

I made another approach. It is based on jQueryMobile but can also be used with normal jQuery after a few minor modifications. The basic is simple: you call a function that opens the popup and adds two buttons that react on functions that you provide by calling the opener-function. Here is my example:

```
function jqConfirm(data) {
    var container = $('#genericConfirm');
    container.find('h1').html(data.title); // title of the confirm dialog
    container.find('p').html(data.message); // message to show
    // .off('click') removes all click-events. click() attaches new events
    container.find('.yes').off("click").click(data.yes); // data.yes/no are functions that you provide
    container.find('.no').off("click").click(data.no);
    container.popup({ positionTo: "window" }).popup("open"); // .popup("open") opens the popup
}
var confirmData = {
    title: "Send this message?",
    message: "Are you sure you want to send this message?",
    yes: function() {
        sendMessage();
        $('#genericConfirm').popup("close");
    },
    no: function() {
        $('#genericConfirm').popup("close");
    }
};
jqConfirm(confirmData); // you open the popup with this function (indirectly)
```

And the HTML part (jQueryMobile specific, must be modified a bit to match plain jQuery)

```
<div data-role="popup" id="genericConfirm" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Message</p>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-theme="a" class="no">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-theme="g" class="yes">Ok</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach another handler to the button that deals with the logic. After you are done with the dialog, simply remove the dialog to get rid of the handlers. If you create an other dialog later, maybe with the same or an other layout, you can define different handlers for that dialog. As events 'bubble' up, both the handler on the button itself, as the handler on html (that only fires when the button is clicked), will be fired.

The following is merely pseudo-code, but it should give you an idea what you can do with this:

```
//This will create the html for your dialog
createMyFancyDialog();
showDialog();

//This is where you'll do the logic for this dialog
$('#confirmation_yes').on( 'click', function() {
    doWhatEveryIWantToDo();

    //After this dialog is done, destroy the dialog.
    //This will get rid of the handlers we don't need in a future dialog.
    //The handler attached to html will persist.
    destroyDialog();
} );
$('#confirmation_no').on( 'click', function() {
    doSomethingMean();

    //After this dialog is done, destroy the dialog.
    //This will get rid of the handlers we don't need in a future dialog.
    //The handler attached to html will persist.
    destroyDialog();
} );
```

Comment: The problem is that I want this dialog to be multiple purpose. So in one page, the confirmation results in something completely different than in another page. That's why I wanted it to be like confirmAction(function(result){ // do what I want in this page });

Comment: Then you define something different for the handler on a different page. All the common stuff you put on a shared javascript file (e.g. the animation for showing and hiding the dialog) with a named function (e.g. `showDialog()`). Everything that is different, you can put in click handlers in a different file.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to rewrite and fix your code, but there are too many things to adjust.

So, I strongly recommend you to rewrite your code in a simpler way, like this:

```
<button id="element">Element</button>
<div id="popup_panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>Your msg?</p>
  <button id="confirmation_yes" >Yes</button>
  <button id="confirmation_no">No</button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#confirmation_yes').click(actionConfirmed);
  $('#confirmation_no').click(actionNotConfirmed);
  $('#element').click(showPopupPanel);
});

function actionConfirmed() {
  $('#popup_panel').slideUp();

  // User confirmed. Now continue.
  // e.g. alert('Yes was clicked');
}

function actionNotConfirmed() {
  $('#popup_panel').slideUp();

  // User said no.
}

function showPopupPanel() {
  $('#popup_panel').slideDown();
}
</script>
```

You can see this code in action here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/LGTSK/

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='yes' type="button" value="Yes" data-result="Yes" />
    <input id='no' type="button" value="No" data-result="No" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var result;
    function confirmAction() {
        if (result)    alert(result);
        else           setTimeout(confirmAction, 100);
    }

    $(function() {
        $('#yes, #no').on('click', function(e) {
            result = $(this).attr('data-result');
        });

        confirmAction()
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```